# (Bitmap)image behaves differently than new Bitmap(image)

Tags: c#, .net, colors

Here is the test i wrote and that will currently fail:

```
var unusableColor = Color.FromArgb(13, 19, 20, 19);
var retrievedColor = Color.Empty;
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1))
{
    bitmap.SetPixel(0, 0, unusableColor);
    bitmap.Save(tempFile, ImageFormat.Png);
}

using (var image = Image.FromFile(tempFile))
// This will lead to the error
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(image))
// But this will work
//using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)image)
{
    retrievedColor = bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
}

Assert.That(retrievedColor, Is.SameAs(unusableColor));
```

If you take a look into the `retrievedColor` you'll find that it will be the same as `Color.FromArgb(13, 19, 19, 19)`. So the difference will be that the green part has changed from 20 to 19.

Any idea why this happens or under which circumstances the constructor of the Bitmap will change a pixel?

#### Update

Seems to be a deeper nested problem. By replacing the `Bitmap` constructor by a simple cast of the image variable the problem goes away. This maybe solves the problem, but it doesn't explain it. Further more i was able to reproduce the problem even in Paint.Net by the following procedure:

- Open Paint.Net and create a new image (size doesn't matter)
- Select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Remove the selection (<kbd>Del</kbd>)
- Open the color dialog (<kbd>F8</kbd>)
- Enter the above values for RGB (19, 20, 19) and at the bottom the transparency (13).
- Select the fill tool (<kbd>F</kbd>)
- Fill the color into the empty image
- Select the color selection tool (<kbd>K</kbd>)
- Click somewhere into your fresh image and watch the color dialog

So it seems it is maybe a deeper problem, not caused by the Bitmap or Image class but maybe by some deeper functionality like GDI+ or something similar.

#### Update 2

I just wrote a new test to find out all affected colors:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 256; r++)
    {
        for (int g = 0; g < 256; g++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
            {
                using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1))
                {
                    var desiredColor = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
                    bitmap.SetPixel(0, 0, desiredColor);

                    // This will fail in a lot of colors with a low alpha channel value
                    using (var copiedBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap))
                    // This will work, cause the information is entirely copied.
                    //using (var copiedBitmap = (Bitmap)bitmap.Clone())
                    {
                        var retrievedColor = copiedBitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);

                        if (desiredColor != retrievedColor)
                        {
                            Debug.Print(desiredColor + " != " + retrievedColor);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please don't let it run completely on itself, cause it will take a loonng time to finish and it also finds a looots of differences. But what you can see, if you play around with the transparency (setting to 1 or 10) then you'll see that the RGB values use this as some kind of bit depth.

So the problem occurs if you create a new Bitmap from an existing one that uses low transparency values. The real root cause seems to be far down in GDI, Kernel or somewhere in this area and can't be solved from .Net.

Simply be aware that a color can change by calling the bitmap constructor if the color has a low transparency value. If you really need the original colors to stay alive in a second instance instead use `(Bitmap)myBitmap.Clone()` or if you load it from disk use `(Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filename)` cause `Image` is only an abstract class which will normally instantiated through the `Bitmap` class.

Comment: Possibly related to a rounding problem due to a round trip to pre-multiplied alpha.

Comment: The problem is in 'new Bitmap(image)'. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I checked PNG file saved with your code using Paint.NET and pixel color is exactly `unusableColor`.
If you change your reading code with this:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(tempFile))
{
    retrievedColor = bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
}
```

everything works

Comment: Yes, this works. But in my eyes this raises more questions on than it answers. Why behaves the explicit converter differently than the constructor of the bitmap type?

Comment: @Oliver: that's a GOOD question I'm not able to answer to. I imagine that when a new bitmap is created some variable (for example pixel type? color space?) is set in a different way than when just casting existing image to bitmap. I really don't know, I'm sorry. Mine is just a solution, not an answer...

Comment: Agreed.  The flaw is in the Bitmap(Image) constructor, it uses Graphics.DrawImage() to make the copy.  DrawImage() makes shortcuts, it was made for human eyes.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Clone method:

```
    using (var image = Image.FromFile(tempFile))
    {
        using (var bitmap = image.Clone() as Bitmap)
        {
            retrievedColor = bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Problem is in 'new Bitmap(image)' because it creates new instance. If you look into bitmap's constructor, it creates new transparent image and draws source image. graphics object has smoothing mode property, which is used for drawing quality. default is no antialiasing.

Here is the Bitmap's constructor:

```
Graphics graphics = null;
try
{
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(this);
    graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    graphics.DrawImage(original, 0, 0, width, height);
}
finally
{
    if (graphics != null)
    {
        graphics.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So if you just load image from file, or clone, bitmap data is same.

Comment: Remember that `Clone` creates a copy of your image; if it's small this is not a problem, otherwise you're wasting memory without any need ;)

Comment: I think that the trick here is not the `Clone()`. In fact it is the `as Bitmap` that does the *magic*. If you simply remove the `Clone()` it will also work and than it is the same solution as Marco provided.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: yes i doesn't do any magic, but `image as Bitmap` behaves differently than `new Bitmap(image)`. The problem is that the ctor does something else by a given image than if it loads the picture from disk.